# Setting multiple breakpoint in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, breakpoints

I would like to set breakpoint all `Convert.ToInt32` lines.

I have tried to replace all `Convert.ToInt32` to `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); Convert.ToInt32` but it did not work because some of the `Convert.ToInt32` methods are parameter. So I wrote a regex replacement which insert the  `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();` at the begining of the all Convert.ToInt32 lines. It seems working but is there any easy way of doing this?

ps: I do not think "Debug -> New Breakpoint -> Break at Function" works with System methods.

**Update:**
I have written a small code

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int test = System.Convert.ToInt32("x");

        System.Console.Write(test);
    }
}
```

I have changed my "Tools -> Options -> Debugging" settings[image: Tools -> Options -> Debugging]

But it is still **not work**ing [image]

Comment: Yes, they are similar but the answer is not solve my problem.

Comment: I am sorry if i am not understanding  you,thats why i ask....cant you just click the left grey bar(breakpoit bar) in the code editing window?

Comment: @terrybozzio :) of course i can click the left grey bar but i have dozens of Convert.ToInt32 lines and I want to set breakpoint all of these lines.

Answer (score 2):

**Turn off** the "`Enable Just My Code`" setting in the Debugging configuration and **Enable** `.net framework source stepping`. Now you can add  `Break at Function` option

Comment: I have done the above settings but it does not work. I have written a small program for this issue but "break at function" does not set breakpoint for System.Convert.ToInt32... 
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int test = System.Convert.ToInt32("x");
    }
}

Comment: I have tested and working fine for me, thats why posted as answer.

Comment: I'm not sure but it can be related with http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/783679/net-framework-source-debugging-does-not-work

Comment: I would also check `Enable address-level debugging` and `Show disassembly if source is not available` in the Debugging Options dialog